# How to pass php value in java script function

Tags: javascript, php

```
<script>
var test = 1;
<?php
$id = "document.write(test)" ;
//echo $id;
//here i want to run sql code 
?>
var id =<?php echo $id; ?>;
alert(id);
</script>
```

fist i want pass **test** value to **php id** 
second i wanna pass **php id** value to **var id** .
*when i run this code alert says Undefined* . 
**How to display id in a alert.**

Comment: You can only pass something from PHP to JavaScript by AJAX.

Comment: please send me some examples

Comment: Go google ajax test some of the example / tutorial scripts. If you then have an error come back to SO and post your question again

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to put quotes. `id` is a string, and PHP does not echo the quotes when it echoes a string. Change it to:

```
var id = "<?php echo $id; ?>";
```